Force reboot if `fstab` mount fails instead of going to emergency mode
I have a fstab with read-only root-fs
and also a rw /var mounted on a USB reader with a µSD in it.
Sometimes at boot time system fails to mount /var. 
It looks like the system cannot find the partition on the µSD. 
My best guess is that the USB reader might be failing or not being enumerated in time.  In this case, the system goes to emergency mode. 
If I reboot, it will just boot fine and /var will be mounted fine.
I was wondering if there is a way to force reboot if any of the mount points in fstab fail to mount, instead of going to emergency mode.
I looked at fstab options and systemd mount options,
but I couldn't find anything.
BTW, I do not want to us nofail because I need /var to be mounted.
/etc/fstab:
PARTUUID=00e91e3a-01  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro          0       2
PARTUUID=00e91e3a-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime,ro  0       1
PARTUUID=90ddf375-01  /var            btrfs   defaults,x-systemd.mount-timeout=30s,x-systemd.device-timeout=30s  0       0

Boot error photo:


The emergency shell is started by the emergency.service unit. If you want different behavior, you can override the ExecStart value for this unit by placing an override file in /etc/systemd/system/emergency.service.d.
E.g. something like:
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/emergency.service.d
cat > /etc/systemd/system/emergency.service.d/override.conf <<EOF
[Service]
ExecStartPre=
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl reboot
EOF

(We're overriding ExecStartPre here because the default behavior is to wait for plymouth, the boot ui, to exist -- but if we're going to reboot there's no point in doing that, since we won't be interacting with anybody at the console.)
